# Byobu nested sessions - hide second bottom bar

Tags: gnu-screen, byobu

When nesting Byobu sessions, how can I hide the parent bottom hardstatus bar?

For example, if I SSH from Pi1 into Pi2, I should only see Pi2's bottom bar.

Please note I am using screen backend, and would prefer to continue to do so. But please feel free to contribute a tmux backend answer for reference as well, in case anyone else has the same question, or perhaps I switch to tmux in the future.